# LIST in Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird, string-aggregation

I can't create query, because function LIST in Firebird doesn't work. Any of them doesn't work:

```
SELECT LIST(ID, '-') FROM SPECS;
SELECT LIST(ID) FROM SPECS;
SELECT LIST(ID, ASCII_CHAR(13)) FROM SPECS;
SELECT LIST(ID || ASCII_CHAR(13)) FROM SPECS;
SELECT LIST(ID || '-') FROM SPECS;
```

and etc. Error text below:

```
An error was found in the application program input parameters for the SQL statement.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -804.
Function unknown.
LIST.
```

I know what it means, but i can't deal with it

Comment: The first one works for me. Are you sure you are using Firebird 2.5?

Comment: Use `select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') from rdb$database` to check is it really FB 2.5 as you think.

Comment: What is the ODS of your database? Sometimes features are only available when the database is he native ODS of that version (eg for Firebird 2.5 that would be ODS 11.2). You can check it through `gstat -h <your-db>`; tools like flamerobin usually also have an option to display it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this example and you will know how it should work

```
SELECT LIST(trim(p.RDB$FIELD_NAME), '; ') 
FROM RDB$FIELDS p
```